# Scripting: How to target specific pom.xml file and extract specific value in a tag

Tags: xml, linux, bash, unix, maven

I am trying to accomplish the following tasks:

1. Find all the files in the directories hierarchy called "pom.xml". (Do not show results)
2. Then I will identify those "pom.xml" with a parent/artifactId of "Maven_CAS_Parent" or "Maven_JAB_Parent". (I need the pom.xml path and the parent artifactId)
3. After filtering, among in-scope "pom.xml"s, I try to extract the parent/version value into a text file called "check.txt". (Here I need the parent version)

One of the "pom.xml"s looks like this (simplified version):

```
<properties>
    <jiraKey>ORCAP</jiraKey>
    <commonName>${jiraKey} - CASDOP</commonName>
    <ear>CAS_ORCAP_EAR</ear>
    <war>CAS_ORCAP_WAR</war>
        <cas.version>1.4</cas.version>
        <cas.dep.version>1.3</cas.dep.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <artifactId>Maven_CAS_Parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>csju.maven</groupId>
    <version>1.4.38</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>dgy.orcap</groupId>
        <artifactId>IHSB_ORCAP</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>${commonName}</name>
<description>none</description>
<url>${siteURL}${project.groupId}</url>
```

That being said, I want an output in this order: the path of the pom file, the parent artifcatId, the parent version. For example:

```
NSS-BUILD3-JOB1/pom.xml    Maven_CAS_Parent    1.4.38
```

I am pretty new to this but I got the following command. I know this command is not working and does not create a check.txt file, but how can I fix it or write a new one?

```
#!/bin/bash
check()
{
echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:parent/x:version/text()' | xmllint --shell pom.xml | grep -v /
}

find . -type f -name pom.xml | xargs grep 'Maven_CAS_Parent\|Maven_JAB_Parent' | Check
```

Comment: move the grep and the `if ... fi` block into a separate script, then call it `find ... | xargs /path/to/myMavenFinder.sh`. Good luck.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, I will give it a try and thank you. But I am trying to write a single script that accomplish all of those.

Comment: Incidentally, +1 for excellent first post, that included example input, required output AND gasp, an attempt to solve your problem. Keep posting and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looping over the files found by `find` as shown in the example below:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
    artifactId=$(xmllint --format --shell "$file" <<< "cat //parent/artifactId/text()" | grep -v /)
    if [[ $artifactId =~ ^(Maven_CAS_Parent|Maven_JAB_Parent)$ ]]
    then
        version=$(xmllint --format --shell "$file" <<< "cat //parent/version/text()" | grep -v /)
    else
        artifactId="Out of scope"
        version=""
    fi
    echo "$file $artifactId $version"    
done < <(find . -type f -name "pom.xml")
```

You will probably need to fix the xpaths to get them to work for you.

Comment: Thank you dogbane, I just modified the post and remove the if function since I don't really need to display the out-of-scope poms. Anyway your edition seems better and I will play around with your post and see it what I can get from it.